# MYSQL query magically grabs numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (`user_profiles`) WHERE `user_id` = $user_id LIMIT 1
```

`$user_id` is a URI segment. For instance `$user_id = 64` would produce

```
SELECT * FROM (`user_profiles`) WHERE `user_id` = '64' LIMIT 1
```

If I add alphabetical characters to the user id, e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/profile/64kjdsg`

I get:

```
SELECT * FROM (`user_profiles`) WHERE `user_id` = '64kjdsg' LIMIT 1
```

which still returns the correct data although there is no user id equal to `64kjdsg`. The user id column in my table is int(11). The query seems to automatically grab the numeric value from 64kjdsg and match that in the db table. Is this a MYSQL function I'm not aware of?

How is this happening? I'm querying using the Codeigniter framework if that makes ant difference.

**UPDATE:** found a similar question [MySQL integer comparison ignores trailing alpha characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574807/mysql-integer-comparison-ignores-trailing-alpha-characters)

Comment: If you throw quotes around the user id in the query I believe it is treated initially as text. If you remove the quotes you should get a mysql error upon non-numeric input

Comment: This is not real code, is it? In MySQL, back ticks are used in table or column names, not in strings.

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario, oops my mistake, I corrected the code. It does not have back ticks in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are comparing to a numeric column, MySQL casts your string to a number (so it removes everything from the occurance of the first non-number character). It's its [default behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html):

```
mysql> select '23andthensome' + 4;
+---------------------+
| '23andthensome' + 4 |
+---------------------+
|                  27 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                           |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '23andthensome' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec
```

So, make more proper queries, check beforehand wether something is a number (`filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,$id);`), only use it when it is, and then: don't send it as a string to MySQL: if you want to compare numbers, send the number, which should not be quoted.

Alternatively, you can let MySQL do the work, but it seems a waste:

```
mysql> select 23 = '23andthensome';
+----------------------+
| 23 = '23andthensome' |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
mysql> select cast(23  as CHAR) = '23andthensome';
+-------------------------------------+
| cast(23  as CHAR) = '23andthensome' |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   0 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in your script is urlsegment integer. You can use `ctype_digit` to do it. If isn't, don't touch your db. Say "No such user"

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://ideone.com/khpEv, it is called type juggling. If you **'64kjdsg'** string will be converted to integer (64) because user_id is INT else it will produce syntax error.

PHP example:

```
<?php
echo (int) '64kjdsg'; // 64
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is security hole
however, if

```
$user_id = 5;
```

result is

```
SELECT * FROM (`user_profiles`) WHERE `user_id` = 5 LIMIT 1
```

not

```
SELECT * FROM (`user_profiles`) WHERE `user_id` = `5` LIMIT 1
```

try to use `intval()`

```
$user_id = intval($user_id);
```