# MySql Select query returns record , when WHERE condition not true

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

MySQL query returns a record, even when the condition not satisfied.

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_id = '10000R'
```

There is no record that will match the WHERE condition given here.
But MySQl return a record with order_id = 10000

Looks like WHERE condition ignoring the alpha within quotes.
Please help me if there is anything wrong in the query or is this a MySql bug

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that `order_id` is an `int`, and that MySql is implicitly casting the varchar `'10000R'` to match the data type of the column, which strips the trailing `'r'`.

See "[Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//type-conversion.html)" in the MySql docs.

Answer (score 2):

The order_id is probably an integer field of some type.  MySQL will cast the string '1000R' to an integer 1000.  That's why you're getting the result back.  It's not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your order_id field is not an integer or other numeric field.  If it is, it might be ignoring the trailing alpha.

[MySQL integer comparison ignores trailing alpha characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574807/mysql-integer-comparison-ignores-trailing-alpha-characters)

Comment: ... and those are the three of the fastest same answers you'll ever get.  :)

Answer (score -1):

MySql table data type is VARCHAR.
please change your data type.